# How can I get Entity Framework to create 2 tables for 2 classes inheriting from the same base class?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following:

```
public abstract class Effort 
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    // ...
}

public class Event : Effort
{
    // ...
}

public class Job: Effort
{
    // ...
}
```

Instead of an Event table and a Job table, I get an Effort table. How do I get two distinct tables?

And on a related note, is there an fluent command I then need to do for this?

```
public class Signup : IAuditTrail, IPrimaryEntities
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Effort Effort { get; set; }
    public int EffortId { get; private set; }
    // ...
}
```

As it can point to either an Event or a Job.

My DbContext is:

```
public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
public DbSet<Signup> Signups { get; set; }
```

Comment: [Table-per-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you. And interestingly, in that article it says "In many cases, TPT shows inferior performance when compared to TPH. See the performance docs for more information" so I may not want to do this.

Comment: Table per concrete type is what you would be likely looking for. TPT uses a table for common fields then specific tables for the subclass specific fields. TPC uses just a table per sub-class where common properties are in each table. TPC should have no performance penalty compared to TPH, if anything it should be faster where you are querying individual subclasses given indexes will be across that subclass table rather than one huge one. It also means not having to rely un lots of null-able columns where they are required for specific subclasses.

Comment: @StevePy So TPC is the `builder.ToTable("Events")` where I end up with an Event & Job (but no Effort) table while TPT is where there is an Effort, Event, & Job table? And to your point, TPC is optimum and TPT/TPH can each be better depending on the use case, but both are generally inferior to TPC? TIA.

Comment: TPT acts more like a composition across the inherited types and would be the more space efficient but slower to query since it always needs to join tables.  TPC would offer better performance. Honestly I avoid inheritance in data models as much as possible but where I do use it, I almost invariably opt for TPC unless they are essentially nearly identical barring a discriminator, then I might use TPH.  I do use composition a fair bit in data structures where, like classes I'm defining "has a" relationships rather than "is a". From a table perspective those look pretty much like TPT.

Comment: The difference between Composition vs. TPT is composition the root table represents the entity without any inheritance. The composed tables can represent information specific to details about that particular record that might be expensive to load (and not commonly needed) or optional in nature. I.e. User -> UserProfile where the profile pic has image and other user's profile data in a one-to-one relationship with user. UserProfile does not extend user, it supliments it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get TPC is in the **base** class to do the following:

```
public class EffortConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Effort>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Effort> builder)
    {
        builder.UseTpcMappingStrategy();
    }
}
```